# Entire WooCommerce Product Page disappearing after entering the Lightbox

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, fancybox, lightbox

I'm in a bit of a pickle.

I'm trying to fix a bug where clicking on the slider on a WooCommerce single product page opens a Lightbox like normal, but after closing it the entire page is blank white.

https://ofironandoak.com/product/zebra-pattern-cowhide/

Elsewhere on the site, the Fancybox the Total theme uses dims the background while keeping content visible. Only here on the WooCommerce product page the content disappears when the page dims, which makes me think the whole outer-wrap is being hidden somehow.

I'm not great with java/jquery so while I think this is probably a conflict between plugins, the only recourse I would have is turning each one off and on and checking to see if anything is fixed. Unfortunately there's a bunch of plugins, and even if I found the culprit I'm not sure I'll be able to rectify the conflict.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `animsition` plugin that fades-out entire page when fancybox starts after clicking image links. So, either remove that plugin or configure properly so that it would not start on links targeting images.

Comment: I turned off the fade-out page animation in the theme options and it's fixed! Thank you so much for your help